# Benchmark function that is both CPU-bound and memory-bound?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, hpc

I am deploying an algorithm on an HPC system and want to tune the amount of resources I request to optimize the performance of the algorithm. I have come across several applications I can use to find the ideal number of CPUs (e.g. https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html), but would like to also tune the amount of memory I allocate. Are there any common benchmark functions or applications to test CPU *and* memory allocation? Ideally, the runtime of such a function would decrease as more resources are allocated, but should also reach a point of diminishing returns.

Comment: What do you mean by "tune the amount of memory I allocate"? For a given dataset, the amount of memory is driven by the dataset, isn't it?

Comment: What you want is very unclear to me and it looks like I am not alone. It looks like you want a benchmark. Did you look for HPCG which is a quite standard benchmark for HPC machines? (Note the previous was the famous LINPACK but it is far from being representative of HPC applications). As for the "memory allocation", the sentence "* the runtime of such a function would decrease as more resources are allocated*" make no sense to me. How doing more stuff or managing more resources is supposed to be faster?